# How to add two buttons in a bar in linear view in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have **two buttons** in a **linear view** and I want to add them to a bar.

How can I create a **bar that appears at the bottom with the buttons** in it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a relativelayout to make a bar appear bottom always like

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <!-- Here you put your buttons -->
    </LinearLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use

1. a `FrameLayout`: http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/create-floating-view-using-framelayout/
2. a `RelativeLayout`: http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/ui-design-keep-the-bar-floating/